# What happens when first child process exits, then parent exits without calling wait?

Tags: unix, process, operating-system, fork

After fork call, the child calls exit() and parent then exits normally. Does the child become orphan and gets init as parent? If this is the case, shouldn't I see the process as zombie until init calls wait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gets reparented (adopted) by `init`. Yes, you'll see a zombie process until `init` calls `wait()`--but `init` calls `wait()` straightaway, so you're never going to catch the zombie process in practice. `init` is very good about immediately reaping zombie processes reparented to it.